# How do I use water?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have just got a super computer which requires water to research. However I can't work out how to collect the water for use.

I tried mopping the water which seemed to just remove it as it didn't go into the duplicate's "carried" section.

I then tried to research the liquid handling and I built a pump in the water, but I then noticed the output and input symbols and the overlay for it, this showed that there was no input on the supercomputer so I'm not sure if building a pipe to it would work.

Since I have all but gas and decor researches, I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Not a direct answer but this guy found a way for infinite water http://forums.kleientertainment.com/klei-bug-tracker/oni-alpha/infinite-water-r2779/

Answer (score 2):

Duplicants will automatically collect water and carry it to the supercomputer, as long as they have access to a source. All you need to do is open up a path to some water, set a research topic, and the dupes will take care of the rest themselves.

Some other water-consuming equipment, such as the microbe musher, planter boxes, and algae terrariums work the same way.

Any equipment that requires water and has an input/output for pipes, however, will require that the water get pumped in via those connections.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need something like this:

[image: answer for your question]

With this, you will get you water source. With this Duplicants can collect water and use it.
After that, if you have some amount of "mopped" water (bottled water), build Bottle Emptier, and i suggest to do something like this:

[image: kindly suggestion]

Make reservoir with clean water, and build these two. With this you got 
centralized system of clean water.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to get water, just get a path to it and set the super computer's priority to 9. Also, you can assign a Research job to a duplicant to make sure that they research, and they will always go and get the water needed to make the research work. If all else fails, then there may be something wrong with your game.

-Make sure your duplicants can get to it, because they can omly reach 3 blocks down!

Comment: They can definitiely get to it, since they could build a pump in it but still no luck.

Comment: okay, when I played the game today, it seems the dupes have no problem getting the water so I'm guessing this was some sort of bug.

Answer (score 0):

Dupes collect the needed water automatically as soon they can access a water source. ("Mob" water seems to be possible, but the amount of water is extremely small and dupes works forever to get enough water for the computer or the Microbe Musher).

You should create access to a clean (!) water source by digging or building a ladder to the water. Dupes don't collect polluted water.